# migrate to a older version of google API

Tags: android, performance

Eclipse shows that my Google API is 19 and platform is 4.4 
i am getting some null pointer exceptions (similar null pointer exceptions to other people in 4.4),IN other forums it is suggested to migrate to a previous version(suspecting a bug with the current version)
how to migrate to a previous version ??
possibly to 4.2 (with steps)

please help

Comment: What actually you want to do with Google API ?

Comment: @N.Nihar Where your logcat error ?  And what actually you want now ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Need to download that in SDK Manager ,Select and install the appropriate packages.